# How to make connection of pdi job with docker database?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to run jobs in docker environment. I have a transformation which transfers data from one table to another table, but It gives me error of database connectivity.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  pdijobs:
    image: pdijobs
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ./data/jasper-data:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - datawarehouse-db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgresql
      DB_HOST: datawarehouse-db
      DB_NAME: data-warehouse
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: admin

  datawarehouse-db:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: data-warehouse
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgdata:
```

Error Message it shows while I compose:

```
Exception in thread Thread-7:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
   File "site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
   requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url:http+docker://localnpipe/v1.30/containers/f369becca473614682584ad742180eaca133178862820c85b26b5d384f4e22b5/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1
```

Comment: did you try to start first the db, wait a minute and then start the application?

Comment: Can you update the question with the error message that you get?